# lmer multilevel fit with intercept constraint

Tags: r, regression, lme4

I regularly have this problem: I want to fit a multilevel regression, with constraint. I don't know how to do that. I usualy end up using `lavaan`, as it allows to set constraints on the regression coefficients. But still it can't have random slope models (only random intercept, and truth is I don't know how to set a constraint on the intercept in `lavaan` either), and I would like to have a multilevel approach.

So basically I have `y` variable having a second order polynomial dependence on `x`, with coefficients depending on the subject `ID`:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.table(x = rep(0:10,5),ID = rep(LETTERS[1:5],each = 11))
df[,a:= rnorm(1,2,1),by = ID]
df[,b:= rnorm(1,1,0.2),by = ID]
df[,y := rnorm(.N,0,10) + a*x + b*x^2 ]

ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color = ID))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

and I can do normall multilevel:

```
lmer(y ~ x + I(x^2) + (x+ I(x^2)|ID),df)
```

But I would like to constrain the intercept to be 0. Is there a simple way to do so ? 
Thank you

Comment: more generally, if you want to constrain *slopes* (or you want to constrain intercepts to a non-zero value) you can often do this with *offsets*. If you want to constrain the parameters in a different way, you can see `?lme4::modular` for ways to break up the fitting process and add constraints at the nonlinear optimization step ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress the intercept with `-1`. For example:

```
coef(summary(lmer(y ~ x + I(x^2) + (x+ I(x^2)|ID),df)))
             Estimate Std. Error    t value
(Intercept) -1.960196   4.094491 -0.4787398
x            2.535092   1.754963  1.4445275
I(x^2)       1.015212   0.130004  7.8090889

coef(summary(lmer(y ~ -1 + x + I(x^2) + (x+ I(x^2)|ID),df)))
       Estimate Std. Error  t value
x      1.831692  0.9780500 1.872800
I(x^2) 1.050261  0.1097583 9.568856
```

Comment: Wow, great and simple. Is there something that simple for the coeffs ?

Comment: To remove predictors you can use `update`. If your original model fit is `m <- lmer(y ~ +x + I(x^2) + (x+ I(x^2)|ID),df)` then to remove `x` you can do `m2 <- update(m, .~.-x)`